# Flutter. Как задать отступы между вложенными элементами stack?

Tags: flutter

Создал `card` во Flutter и в нем `Stack`.
В Stack Находятся:

- Дата(`dates[index]`),
- Название(`names[index]`)
- Изображение(`images[index]`).

Если название или изображение слишком длинные, то они накладываются друг на друга.
Необходимо сделать отступы.

Вот код Card:

```
return Container(
          height: 150,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
          key: Key([dates[index], names[index], images[index]].join(';')),
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)
            ),
            elevation: 10,
            color: cardColor,
            child:
              Stack(
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    title: Text(dates[index], style: LabelTextStyle),
                    subtitle: Text(names[index], style: textStyle)
                  ),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                        child:
                          Image.network(images[index]),
                    )
                  ),
                  Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            dates.removeAt(index);
                            names.removeAt(index);
                            images.removeAt(index);
                          });},
                          icon: Icon(Icons.delete_rounded),
                          color: mainColor,
                        ),
                    )
                ]
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Должно получиться это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А получается это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно задать отступ у ListTile, но он создается от края контейнера, а изображения все разного размера.

Я пробовал сделать Row, в него поместить все это - выдает ошибку.

Comment: Сорри за мою невнимательность-поспешность. Да, тут `Row` предполагается (для разделения контента карточки на два столбца). _«выдает ошибку»_ - какую именно?

Comment: В том как сделано сейчас - проблема не в отступах, а в наползании виджетов друг на друга: `ListTile` расползся из-за ширины содержащегося в нем текста, и подлез под контейнер с изображением. Если через выровненные контейнеры делать (по-моему, это неок потому что является усложнением решения), то придется задать такую ширину каждому контейнеру, чтобы наползания не происходило. Ну а в общем, помимо маржинов/паддингов, отступы можно делать пустым виджетом `SizedBox` (указав ему только размеры).

Comment: @yar85 Программа зависает и открывается box.dart

Comment: А как делать с помощью SizedBox?

Comment: _«А как делать с помощью SizedBox?»_ - просто вставлять этот виджет (с указанными в аргументах размерами) между других виджетов. В данном случае, это не поможет, то есть не устранит перекрытие/наползание виджетов... такое перекрытие - это нормальное, ожидаемое поведение виджетов внутри `Stack`'а: он применяется как раз для размещения дочерних виджетов друг над другом (то есть, для устранения наползания - надо использовать другой виджет в роли родительского... такой как `Row`).

Comment: Создавая `Row` у меня открывается Box.dart и выделяется `throw FlutterError.fromParts(<DiagnosticsNode>[`

Comment: И что? Это же проблема из-за неких неизвестных ошибок в твоем отдельно взятом коде, а не проблема фреймворка (само по себе, использование `Row` ошибок не вызывает)... решай эту проблему, устраняй ошибку. Этот вопрос задан вообще не об ошибке - он задан об отступах внутри `Stack`, и насчет отступов вроде уже объяснено... а ответов тут нет видимо потому, что само использование `Stack` в данном случае не имеет смысла: этот виджет (предназначенный прежде всего для размещения дочерних виджетов "стопкой" друг над другом) просто не подходит к условиям задачи размещения виджетов "в строку".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.  Я переписал код сделал row. Ошибка выдавалась из-за `ListTile`. Без него все работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такая должна быть верстка:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 150,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 10),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        elevation: 10,
        color: Colors.grey[300],
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('1'),
                      Text('2'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
//                 child: Image.network(images[index]),
                    child: Container(color: Colors.grey[500], width: 150),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 10,
              left: 10,
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
//                 setState(() {
//                   dates.removeAt(index);
//                   names.removeAt(index);
//                   images.removeAt(index);
//                 });
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete_rounded),
//               color: mainColor,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```